# Refractory period in action potential

Tags: neuroscience, action-potential

[image]

I know that the part E in this graph is definitely the part of refractory period.

My question : Will there be any effect on B,C or D if a stimulus is given at  time B,CorD respectively ?

Comment: If there is a stimulus at E, there will be depolarization (membrane becomes relatively more positive). It is just that no action potential is fired. Therefore, if a strong stimulus does arrive, it will depolarise the membrane to an extent depending on its strength. It will increase the height of the succeeding B phase or decrease the dip of E phase. If it is strong enough, it might persist above the threshold till the refractory period is over, and then an action potential can be fired.

Comment: @SatwikPasani I'd say that's a great answer, would you like to add it as one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a stimulus at E, there will be depolarization (membrane becomes relatively more positive). It is just that no action potentials are fired. Therefore, if a strong stimulus does arrive, it will depolarize the membrane to an extent depending on its strength. It will increase the height of the succeeding B phase or reduce the dip of the succeeding E phase. If it is strong enough, it might persist above the threshold till the refractory period is over, and then an action potential can be fired.